# Is it a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

\begin{align*}W=\left\{\left\{x_1,x_2,x_3\right\}|x_1-1=\frac{x_2-2}{2}=\frac{x_3-3}{3}\right\}\end{align*}

\begin{align*}\alpha _1=\left\{x_1,x_2,x_3\right\};\\\\&\\\alpha _2=\left\{y_1,y_2,y_3\right\};\end{align*}

Is $W$ a vector space? I know $\alpha _1+\alpha _2$ and to check whether fit the equation, but seems stuck, and have a little problem in the expression.

$x_1+y_1-2=\frac{x_2+y_2-4}{2}=\frac{x_3+y_3-6}{3}$

---

subtract 1 from both sides,

$x_1+y_1-1=\frac{x_2+y_2-2}{2}=\frac{x_3+y_3-3}{3}$

Now we are done.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, answer of my book is yes, but how to prove.

Comment: I was wrong, it **is** a vector space.

Comment: It is easy to check that if $(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in W$, then so is $\lambda (x_1,x_2,x_3) = (\lambda x_1,\lambda x_2,\lambda x_3)$, and if $(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in W$ and $(y_1,y_2,y_3) \in W$ then so is $(x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2,x_3+y_3)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, you should add $1$ to the equality constraint describing your set. Then, you get
$$
x_1 = \frac{x_2}2 = \frac{x_3}3
$$
Now, it should be easy to prove that it is a vector space.

Comment: yes, it is a equation of line.

Comment: @realmatrix note, "it is the equation of a line" is not sufficient to show that it is a vector space. $y=x+1$ is the equation of a line, but the points satisfying that equation do not form a vector space.

Comment: @crf yes, your line doesn't pass zero.

Answer (score -1):

It is not Stright line through origin in R3-space, that's why it cant be the subspace and hence vector space as it doesnot contain in this case the zero vector.

Comment: It does contain the zero vector.